# Pago por paypal en Página Web

Tags: html, paypal

Estoy intentando implementar el pago por PayPal en mi página web, ahorita estoy utilizando *sanbox* para realizar algunas pruebas.

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo incluir alguna variable en los datos que se envían para yo identificar el usuario que pagó? Una podría ser con el correo de quien paga pues se envía automáticamente, pero por ejemplo me gustaría añadir el id de mi usuario, el id está en una base de datos, para poder identificarlo de esta manera.

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código. Sí funciona pero me gustaría pasarle algun otro parametro para identificar el comprador:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="the_prueba-facilitator@live.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="MXN">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Paquete Individual">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/es_XC/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes pasar parámetros usando algunos campos específicos como:

- `custom`: una variable pasada por motivos de identificación, los usuarios no la ven y puede tener un tamaño de hasta 255 caracteres.
- `invoice`: una variable pasada para identificar el número de la factura (*invoice*). Puede tener un tamaño de hasta 127 caracteres.

Con la primera podrías pasar el id interno del usuario y con la segunda podrías pasar el id interno de la factura (con el que podrías identificar al usuario más adelante). En la [documentación de PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#html-variables-for-payment-transactions) encontrarás más información sobre esos campos.

---

Alternativamente, podrías considerar hacerlo de otra manera: en lugar de mandar información interna a PayPal (que realmente no necesitan), podrías especificar una URL a la que se redirigirá al usuario una vez completado el pago.

Para ello podrías usar el parámetro `return` donde pasarías la URL de la página a la que quieres que se redirija al cliente. En esa página mostrarías un mensaje personalizado y en el `GET` (o el `POST` si así lo especificas con el campo `rm`) tendrás la información de la transacción.

Answer (score 3):

Revisando la documentacion de Paypal:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Podes ver que hay una variable llamada "custom", `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="idUsuario">`, el cual permite el paso variable con fines de seguimiento, que los compradores no ven.

Saludos

Comment: Lo intente con esta variable y no me llego ningun valor, intente poniendo algo estatico pero no paso ningun parametro en la descripcion de la compra, no se si tenga algo que ver con esto: _xclick lo intente con x_cart y mismo resultado

Comment: ¿Podrás poner el ejemplo del código que utilizaste?

Comment: Como bien dice @alvaro podes utilizar "rm" (con el valor en "1" para que te lleguen los datos mediante get o "2" para que lleguen por post a la url que le indiques en "return")